# contact form not sending / redirecting

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I have the below codes , and for some reason redirects and I get a Undefined variable: subject in C:\wamp\www\boot\send.php on line 42, as below. Appreciate any assistance I can get.

Line 42 is

```
$go = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:<$from>");
```

Contact us

```
    <body>
<div class='formbody'>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<form id="contact-form" action="send.php" method="POST">

  <p>Dear hidden@gmai..com,</p>
  <p>My
    <label for="your-name">name</label> is
    <input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" minlength="3" placeholder="(your name here)" required> and</p>

  <p>my
    <label for="email">email address</label> is
    <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
  </p>

  <p> I have a
    <label for="your-message">message</label> for you,</p>

  <p>
    <textarea name="your-message" id="your-message" placeholder="(your msg here)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">
      <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
    l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
      </svg>
      <small>SEND PLEASE</small>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bs-animation.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Send.php

```
    <?php
$to = "hidden@gmail.com";
$name = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-name']));
$email = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-email']));
$message = TRIM (stripslashes($_POST['your-message']));

$body ="";
$body .="Name: ";
$body .=$name;
$body."\n";

$body ="";
$body .="Email: ";
$body .=$email;
$body."\n";

$body ="";
$body .="Message: ";
$body .=$message;
$body."\n";


$go = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:<$from>");

if($go) {

    print("message sent");
}

else{

    print("There has been a small error . Sorry!!");
}

?>
```

Comment: you have 2 form open tags. the browser is probably using the first one and posting to self. and then there are a number of error in send.php

Comment: Not the issue you posted about but, `TRIM stripslashes($_post...` is missing a `(` after `trim` and `$_post` needs to be in caps: `$_POST`.

Comment: Your `$body ="";`-rows are totally unnecessary. They don't do anything at all. It means "Append nothing" to the string.

Comment: Yep. There's way too many coding errors for this to be answerable. P.S.: Error_reporting would go a long way to narrow this down.

Comment: An undefined variable is probably a result of not defining the variable.  Or rather where do you assign a value to `$subject`?

Comment: "Undefined variable: subject " because $subject is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not directing you to the send.php is caused by the two form tags. The first form tag will run first and be the reason why it's staying on the same page. To stop this confusion you could give the form an id (like class) using the div tag:

```
<div id="contact-form">
<form action="send.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to condense the 2 form tags:

```
<form id="contact-form">
<form action="send.php" method="post">
```

into one:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="send.php" method="post">
```

Comment: @nogad - That would be a complete essay... :O

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i was writing one, but what's the point now, the OP is just going to accept the first mostly right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<form id="contact-form">`. It's causing an extra form which doesn't exist. Try changing it to a `div`, or putting it in your other form tag, then it'll work fine.